# Add series to a JFreeChart after rendering

Tags: jfreechart

Hi i have a `JFreeChart` that i want to be able to plot and add series to without losing old data.

For example I initially generate the `JFreeChart` from:

```
    public JFreeChart plot(Number[] x, Number[] y, String title, String xLabel,
            String yLabel) {
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries(title);
        if (x.length == y.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                series.add(x[i], y[i]);
            }
            XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(title, xLabel,
                    yLabel, dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false,
                    false);
            return chart;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: [plot] X&Y Vectors of different lengths");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then i would add it to a `ChartPanel` and to my `ContentPane`:

```
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);
contentPane.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

now i need a function that can add an extra series to the plot without forgetting the series already in the dataset (so i cannot just call my plot function again)

**how do I do this?**

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a referance to your `dataset` you can add a new series at any time using `dataset.addSeries(series)`

Comment: How do you get the dataset from a chart/plot. Seems like the only method provided by the chart is ```getPlot```. It also seems like a plot only provides ```getDatasetGroup``` not dataset.